# how to disable auto-refresh in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know what happend, I used to refresh the page in the browser by simply saving the document <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> , but now the page in the browser is updated every time I print something.

I'm not good enough in English and finding the right setting for me is real hell, could you guys tell me how to return everything as it was?

Comment: Are you talking about some kind of hot-reload on a webpack-like dev-server ? And what do you mean by "every time I print something" ? Is the file automatically saving when you type ? If so, you can disable the auto saving feature in the "File" tab > "Auto Save"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to:

`File` →    `Auto Save`.

[image: Image autosave]

Answer (score 6):

Open `settings.json` and add the element `"**"` to liveServer.settings.ignoreFiles array

```
"liveServer.settings.ignoreFiles": [
        ".vscode/**",
        "**/*.scss",
        "**/*.sass",
        "**/*.ts",
        "**" //This bit stops the extension's live reloading feature.
]
```